# Matrix having month(integer) and year(integer), I want it to be extracted in Date or POSIX format using R

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a function created to arrive month, so that if a invoice is created before 15th of a month, will consider previous month. Else it will consider current month. The output gets stored in a matrix (2 columns and 4500 rows). One column is for months in integer and other for year in integer. Program and output below. I want the month and year to be in Date format instead of integer, so that I can slide and dice the data in visualization. Your help is appreciated.

```
# If the date is before 15th of a month, will consider previous month. Else current month
myDateFun <- function(x){
      x <- as.Date(x, format='%d-%m-%Y')
      if (day(x) < 15){
        dd <- x-14 
      }
      else {dd <- x}
      return(c(month(dd), year(dd)))
    }

    # sapply method used to absorb the function and create matrix of month and year
mat = t(sapply(CI3$invoice_date, FUN=myDateFun, simplify='matrix'))

# Output [,1] is month. [,2] is year   
mat
            [,1] [,2]
       [1,]    3 2016
       [2,]    4 2016
       [3,]    5 2016
       [4,]    6 2016
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adjust your function slightly you don't need to use sapply.

```
myDateFun <- function(x){
  x <- as.Date(x, format='%d-%m-%Y')
  ifelse(lubridate::day(x) < 15, dd <- x-14, dd <- x)
  out <- format(dd, "%Y-%m")
  return(out)
}

# add year month to CI3
# year_month will be a character vector due to format function.
CI3$year_month <- myDateFun(CI3$invoice_date)
```

#### ***edit based on comment:***

I edited the function so it can take an extra argument specifying year or month. Default is year. Very simple error handling to make sure it is one of these values.

```
myDateFun <- function(x, period = "year"){
  # error handling
  if(!(period %in% c("year", "month"))) stop("period should be year or month")

  x <- as.Date(x, format='%d-%m-%Y')
  ifelse(lubridate::day(x) < 15, dd <- x-14, dd <- x)
  if(period == "year"){
  out <- format(dd, "%Y")
  } else {
    out <- format(dd, "%b")
  }
  return(out)
}


CI3$year <- myDateFun(CI3$invoice_date, "year")
CI3$month <- myDateFun(CI3$invoice_date, "month")
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. I want the month and year as separate column in %m and %Y format. How to get it

Comment: I added a new function to the answer. You can choose which one you need for your reporting.

Comment: I wanted in %b (or %m) and %Y, so that I can select the date ranges in visualization.

Comment: So what is your exact wanted output? 2016-02, 2016 and 02 or 2016 and "feb"? or 2016-feb? or 2016 and 02 and "feb"?  All can be adjusted in the format functions and if statements in the function.

Comment: I want "Feb" to be stored in a column, and "2016" to be stored in a column. So two new variables to be created

Comment: That's easy. I changed the %m in the function to %b to return "feb" instead of "02"

Comment: I did it on myself, but CI3$year and CI3$month are getting derived as character. Was that the expected output?

Comment: Yes. format returns chars. That makes it consistent for all outputs of format. If you want year in number, either an as.numeric with the year part, or use lubridate's year function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the lubridate and purrr packages. I often just need the month and year of a date so I just default the day to 1 and ignore it.

Here is some sample data in your format:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)

     x <- data_frame(date = c("03/01/2018", "01/02/2015", "03/04/2006", "25/12/2006", "15/01/2014"))
```

This is your function using lubridate:

```
    AltDateFun <- function(x) {
        x <- dmy(x)
        if (day(x) < 15) {
            x <- x - months(1)
            day(x) <- 1
            return(x)
        }
        else {
            day(x) <-1
            return(x)
        }
    }
```

And assuming your invoice dates are a character column in a data frame with dates in the format dmy:

```
    z <- map_df(x, AltDateFun)

    # A tibble: 5 x 1
    x         
    <date>    
    1 2017-12-01
    2 2015-01-01
    3 2006-03-01
    4 2006-11-01
    5 2013-12-01
```

EDIT:

To get the month and year in a separate column do this:

```
    z %>% mutate(m = month(x), y = year(x))

    # A tibble: 5 x 3
    x              m     y
    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
    1 2017-12-01 12.0   2017
    2 2015-01-01 1.00   2015
    3 2006-03-01 3.00   2006
    4 2006-11-01 11.0   2006
    5 2013-12-01 12.0   2013
```

Comment: > z <- map_df(CI3$invoice_date, AltDateFun)
Error in if (day(x) < 15) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
Called from: .f(.x[[i]], ...)

Comment: Is your invoice date in character format? That error tells me lubridate couldn't find a string with a date in dmy format. I've edited the code above to show the libraries I've used and how to get x into a data frame.

Comment: > z <- map_df(CI3$invoice_date, AltDateFun)
Error in if (day(x) < 15) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
Called from: .f(.x[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> Q              (CI3$invoice_date is in Date format.)

Comment: What format is the CI3$invoice_date? The error message is telling you the problem: you need to have the proper character format for the function. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked. Thanks all for your answers. Just sharing the code I used. Updated code below

```
myDateFun <- function(x, period = "year") {
  # error handling
  if (!(period %in% c("year", "month")))
    stop("period should be year or month")

  x <- as.Date(x, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
  ifelse(lubridate::day(x) < 15, dd <- x - 14, dd <- x)
  if (period == "year") {
    out <- format(dd, "%Y")
  } else {
    out <- format(dd, "%b")
  }
  return(out)
}

CI3$invyr <- myDateFun(CI3$invoice_date, "year")
CI3$invmon <- myDateFun(CI3$invoice_date, "month")
CI3$date_m_Y = paste(CI3$invmon, CI3$invyr, sep = "-")
```